# Deploying Calendar list using SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, pnp, pnp-provision

I am trying to create a calendar list using SPFx feature framework. Am able to create custom list with content types but Calendar list is not getting created.

XML for fields

```
<Field ID="{2C665F80-57EA-4632-9CB3-BF85F4DEA4BA}" Group="Test Columns" Type="Text" Name="TestShortDescription" DisplayName="Short Description" Required="TRUE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" MaxLength="255"></Field>
```

XML for Content type

```
<ContentType ID="0x010200D4BB8D5EA0B04541A030DCFE2B96BE49"
        Name="Events"
        Group="Test Content Types"
        Description="Content type used for Events business object">
    <FieldRefs>            
        <FieldRef ID="{2C665F80-57EA-4632-9CB3-BF85F4DEA4BA}" />
    </FieldRefs>
</ContentType>
```

XML for list

```
<ListInstance
                CustomSchema="Events.xml"
                FeatureId="00bfea71-de22-43b2-a848-c05709900100"
                Title="Events"
                Description="Events"
                TemplateType="106"
                Url="Lists/Events">
</ListInstance>
```

XML for list schema

```
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="Events" Type="106" EnableContentTypes="TRUE" FolderCreation="FALSE" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="Lists/Events" BaseType="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
      <MetaData>
        <ContentTypes>
          <ContentTypeRef ID="0x010200D4BB8D5EA0B04541A030DCFE2B96BE49" />
        </ContentTypes>
        <Fields></Fields>
        <Views>
          <View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,objectiv_schema_mwsidcamlidC24;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png" Url="AllItems.aspx">
            <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
            <JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
            <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
            <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
            <ViewFields>
              <FieldRef Name="ID"></FieldRef>
            </ViewFields>
            <Query>
              <OrderBy>
                <FieldRef Name="ID" />
              </OrderBy>
            </Query>
          </View>
        </Views>
        <Forms>
          <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
          <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
          <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
        </Forms>
      </MetaData>
    </List>
```

Reference

1. [Provision SharePoint assets from your SharePoint client-side web
   part](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/provision-sp-assets-from-package)
2. [List element](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/list-element-list)

Comment: is there some kind of an error that you receive as an anwer?

Comment: Yes while trying to add spfx app to site contents, it says Something went wrong and app is not getting added

Answer (score 0):

While technically this should work, as you're finding it's a nightmare trying to find where there's an error in the XML since it's a black box. This is why you've seen so little effort invested in this space in years from Microsoft & rather, investments in REST & site designs/scripts.

In fact, MSFT was torn on even supporting this in SPFx. The guidance to provision assets is that you should use the SharePoint REST API or the site designs/site scripts for creating resources.